# Can we get visible rows and visible columns using ref or any other way from @inovua/reactdatagrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import DataGrid from "@inovua/reactdatagrid-community";
import "@inovua/reactdatagrid-community/index.css";

const columns = [
  { name: "id", header: "ID", defaultVisible: true },
  { name: "name", header: "Name", defaultVisible: true },
  { name: "age", header: "Age", defaultVisible: true }
];

const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "John", age: 25 },
  { id: 2, name: "Jane", age: 30 }
  // Add more data rows here
];

const App = () => {
  const gridRef = useRef(null);

  const handleLogVisibleInfo = () => {
    if (gridRef.current) {
      const visibleColumns = gridRef.current.visibleColumns;
      const visibleRows = gridRef.current.getRenderedData();
      // other code
    } else {
      console.log(gridRef.current);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <DataGrid
        idProperty="id"
        ref={gridRef}
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={data}
        style={{ height: "400px" }}
      />
      <button onClick={handleLogVisibleInfo}>Log Visible Info</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In this code it returns always null in console because this DataGrid might not support ref concept.

Here i am assuming that the data grid component provides a ref that allows us to interact with its internals.

Here's a hypothetical example of how one might access the number of visible columns and visible rows using a ref in a data grid component: